# Spring Cloud Stream: how to republish to dead letter queue and also throw exception

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream

I'm migrating a project that uses Spring AMQP to a project that uses Spring Cloud Stream with RabbitMQ.

In my old project, when some exception occurred while processing a message using @RabbitListener, that exception was thrown. If there was a dead letter queue binded, exception was still thrown (only once if there were retries, the last one I guess). This was very helpful for logging purposes.

In Spring Cloud there is a dead letter queue mechanism for @StreamListener if you define the properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.destination=dest1
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input1.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input1.consumer.republishToDlq=true
```

But if you have a method like this (is just an example):

```
@StreamListener("input1")
public void process(String message){
    System.out.println("Trying...");
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Logs are:

```
Trying...
Trying...
Trying...
(end of log, no exception thrown)
```

Is there any way to throw the exception (only in the last retry)?

Thanks!

Comment: @GaryRussell - Could you please share link to learn Spring Cloud Stream with RabbitMQ in depth? Or How can we learn it ?

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/ Samples: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples The samples README also has a link to https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications which use the current functional programming model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation about consumer properties.

Set `...consumer.max-attempts=1` to disable retry.

Comment: I want to 1) have retries 2) dead queue letter when retries are exhausted 3) throw the last exception, I have all the 3 things when using Spring AMQP.

Comment: Well, you have `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input1.consumer.republishToDlq=true` which means the binder republishes the message the the DLQ (and adds exception information) instead of throwing an exception, which causes the broker to send it to the DLQ, but without exception information. If that's what you want, remove the `republishToDlq` so it defaults to `false`.

Comment: But if I set republishToDql to false, message (without exception) is not republished in the dead letter queue. In the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) it seems to be enough using auto-bind-dlq=true, but if I remove that property, message never arrives to dead letter queue.

Comment: There are two choices - throw an exception and the broker sends the original message to the DLQ or `republishToDlq=true` which means, instead, the binder publishes the message to the DLQ, with additional diagnostics information (exception etc in headers). the auto-bind-dlq simply sets up the DLQ and configures the original queue to send rejections there (for when an exception is thrown). The queue must not already exist without DLQ configuration; you can't change a queue after it is created.

Comment: That was the problem: "The queue must not already exist without DLQ configuration; you can't change a queue after it is created". Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the exception, log it and then throw AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException. This will send the message to dead letter queue

Answer (score 0):

You are under `@StreamListener` where would you expect the exception to go? who is catch it?

you can do it something like that:

```
@StreamListener("input1")
public void process(String message){
    try {
        System.out.println("Trying...");
        throw new RuntimeException();
        // or the actual code that handle the message
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        // handle the exception, logging etc.
        throw re
    }
}
```